# Meaning of assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86

```
mov     ss:ebp+FFFFFBE0,edx : TRG+30
```

ss is stack segment
ebp is base pointer of stack

FFFFFBE0 is jump address 
ebp+FFFFFBE0 its point to memory location of stack

`edx : TRG+30`   ; confused

I think it moving data(edx : TRG+30 ) to location (ebp+FFFFFBE0)

Comment: What program are you running that is showing you this output? I'm assuming `:TRG+30` is a comment possibly giving you an idea where the memory operand is pointing. It isn't part of the instruction IMHO

Comment: Note that it's very likely that `mov [ss:ebp+0xFFFFFBE0],edx` is actually `mov [ss:ebp-0x00000420],edx`.

Answer (score 0):

The code is loading a 4 byte integer from register `edx` into an array/structure called `TRG`.
To be exact it is writing bytes 0x30..0x33 from that structure.

Your debugger is mislabelling the instruction though. It should be:

```
mov [ss:ebp-0x420],edx
```

`edx` is just a register, its contents come from some code prior to the statement shown.
`ebp` is the base pointer which normally points to the storage for local variables in a routine.
`: TRG+30` is a comment inserted by the debugger; it is not part of the instruction.

When interpreting assembly you can never view an instruction in isolation, you must see it as part of a sequence of instructions.

Comment: so  colon : is for comment ?

Comment: What can I say, your debugger is broken.

Comment: @user143252 usually not. Are you sure it was colon? Can't it be your font + resolution + LCD is making a semicolon look almost like colon?

Comment: @Ped7g I zoomed 200% , still it is a colon :                  :)

Comment: how u reach to this value "0x420"

Comment: @user143252 because usual encoding for integer values in computer is using 32 bits (in x86 32b mode), and [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) way is used for negative numbers. So `0xFFFFFBE0` is also `-1056` when treated as signed 32b integer (or `4294966240` as unsigned). In 32b mode the address has 32 bits, so it doesn't matter whether you add 4294966240 and overflow the 32b or subtract 1056, the overflown number will truncate to the same result. In 64b mode the offset is sign-extended, so it would be added as `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFBE0` and again it works as -1056.